# Asynchronous task pattern in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm moving from C# to Java, and I need to implement a set of asynchronous tasks.

I have a good knowledge of Java threading, but I liked .NET's `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` methods because they allowed me to switch from synchronous to asynchronous tasks with ease.

In my case, if I have a set of I/O intensive operations (suitable for changing to async) like the following:

```
DoOperation1();
DoOperation2();
DoOperation3();
```

in .NET I would easily do something like:

```
BeginInvoke(DoOperation1);
BeginInvoke(DoOperation2);
BeginInvoke(DoOperation3);
EndInvoke(Result1);
EndInvoke(Result2);
EndInvoke(Result3);
```

Briefly, my question is: is there anything similar in Java, or do I need to use threads manually "the old way"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want to use *futures* in Java. You submit a task to an [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and receive a [`Future<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) back which you can ask view in a similar way to `Task<T>` from the .NET 4 TPL... you can ask a future for its result in a blocking manner, or with a timeout, ask if it's done etc.

Working with `Callable<T>` isn't as neat as using delegates in C# via method group conversions and lambda expressions, but the basic ideas are similar.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'd probably want to use [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) alongside Runnable or Callable classes that wrap the implementation of the jobs you're trying to run.

An example:

```
SomeTask someTask1 = ...
SomeTask someTask2 = ...

executorService.execute(someTask1);
executorService.execute(someTask2);

executorService.shutdown(); //Close down the service
```